# Any way to force ufw to show the status both verbose and numbered?

Tags: ufw

I can get a non verbose ufw output with numbers (convenient to edit / delete rules based on their number):

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ufw status numbered verbose
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

but I cannot get a verbose (to also display the defaults) output numbered:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ufw status verbose numbered
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Any idea how to get the ufw verbose output, with numbers on the rules (so that I can edit / delete them etc, while being aware of the defaults at the same time?)?

Answer (score 2):

afaik there is no built-in way to display both. But you can just pipe your verbose output to awk to get both, like:

```
me:~$ sudo ufw status verbose | awk '{if ($1 !~ /^[0-9]+/) {print $0} else {print (i++)+1 "\t" $0} }'
```

Result:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1       80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
2       ****/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
3       80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
4       ****/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: In make case this not helped, because I get different indexes in the middle of the output.